# Template Friend Function of a Template Class (Friend with More Parameters)

Tags: c++, templates, friend

I can't get this to work:

```
template<std::size_t s, typename T>
class A;

template<std::size_t s, typename T, typename U>
A<s, T> operator *(U const lhs, A<s, T> const& rhs);

template<std::size_t s, typename T>
class A
{
    // Blabla
    
    template<typename U>
    friend A<s, T> operator * <>(U const lhs, A<s, T> const& rhs);
};
```

This fails to compile with the following error message:

> invalid use of template-id 'operator * <>' in declaration of primary template.

Comment: Why the `<>` after the `operator*` inside the class? What exactly are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @cigien here is my inspiration: (https://web.mst.edu/~nmjxv3/articles/templates.html) It works well for other methods.

Comment: @cigien Actually you are right there is no need for the `<>` after `operator *``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is an additional template parameter (compared to the template class  parameters), it seems that one does not need to add the `<>` after the function name.
In conclusion, this worked fine for me:

```
template<std::size_t s, typename T>
class A;

template<std::size_t s, typename T, typename U>
A<s, T> operator *(U const lhs, A<s, T> const& rhs);

template<std::size_t s, typename T>
class A
{
    // Blabla
    
    template<typename U>
    friend A<s, T> operator *(U const lhs, A<s, T> const& rhs);
};

template<std::size_t s, typename T, typename U>
A<s, T> operator *(U const lhs, A<s, T> const& rhs)
{
    //BlaBla
}
```